# How to avoid running Snakemake rule after input or intermediary output file was updated

Tags: file, caching, build, workflow, snakemake

Even if the output files of a Snakemake build already exist, Snakemake wants to rerun my entire pipeline only because I have modified one of the first input or intermediary output files.

I figured this out by doing a Snakemake dry run with `-n` which gave the following report for updated input file:

```
Reason: Updated input files: input-data.csv
```

and this message for update intermediary files

```
reason: Input files updated by another job: intermediary-output.csv
```

How can I force Snakemake to ignore the file update?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the option `--touch` to mark them up to date:

> --touch, -t
>   Touch output files (mark them up to date without
>                           really changing them) instead of running their
>                           commands. This is used to pretend that the rules were
>                           executed, in order to fool future invocations of
>                           snakemake. Fails if a file does not yet exist.

Beware that this will touch all your files and thus modify the timestamps to put them back in order.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to Eric's answer, see also the [ancient](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#ignoring-timestamps) flag to ignore timestamps on input files.

Also note that the Unix command `touch` can be used to modify the timestamp of an existing file and make it appear older than it actually is:

```
touch --date='2004-12-31 12:00:00' foo.txt 
ls -l foo.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 db291g db291g 0 Dec 31  2004 foo.txt
```

Comment: Yes in fact, if the OP has only one file that is causing trouble, I suggest using  @dariober 's solution of the unix touch by specifying a date older that the next outputs of your workflow.

Answer (score 2):

In case `--touch` (with `--force`, `--forceall` or `--forcerun` as the official documentation says that needs to be used in order to force the "touch" if doesn't work by itself) didn't work out as expected, `ancient` is not an option or it would need to modify too much from the workflow file, or you faced https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/823 (that's what happened to me when I tried `--force` and `--force`*), here is what I did to solve this solution:

1. I noticed that there were jobs that shouldn't be running since I put files in the expected paths.
2. I identified the input and output files of the rules that I **didn't want to run**.
3. In the order of the rules that were being executed and I didn't want to, I executed `touch` on the input files and, after, on the output files (taking into account the order of the rules!).

That's it. Since now the timestamp is updated according the rules order and according the input and output files, snakemake will not detect any "updated" files.

This is the manual method, and I think is the last option if the methods mentioned by the rest of people don't work or they are not an option somehow.