# How to make Snakemake ignore an updated file when determining which input files have changed?

Tags: python, build, workflow, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a *Snakemake* profile that turns input data into output data based on defined rules.

One of the input files has been modified through git, but I don't want rules that use it as input to treat it as modified (the changes are irrelevant here). How do I do this?

A related question is this one, but there the question is asked in a way that I find confusing. The answers are valid though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56804496/7483211